# Reflection-based injection vs. dynamic proxy: Practical considerations?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, interceptor, dynamic-proxy

I'm working on some framework-ish code designed to execute a huge number of operations (hundreds of thousands), all of which use the same basic components, but need to accept operation-specific configuration data from an external source.

Assume for the moment that there's a configuration repository which, given the appropriate list of setting names, knows how to load these settings efficiently and store them in a type like the following:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    dynamic Get(string key);
    void Set(string key, dynamic value);
}
```

What I'm planning to do is implement either some fluent mapping syntax or just decorate the component classes with attributes like so:

```
public class MyComponent : IActivity
{
    [Configuration("Threshold")]
    public virtual int Threshold { get; set; }

    [Configuration("SomeKey", Persistence = ConfigPersistence.Save)]
    public virtual string SomeSetting { get; set; }
}
```

You get the picture... hopefully.  What's important to note is that **some properties actually need to be saved *back* to the repository**, so conventional DI libraries don't work here; and even if they did, they're blunt instruments not designed to be spinning up hundreds of thousands of components and loading/saving millions of attributes. In other words, *I don't think I'm reinventing the wheel*, but if somebody wants to try to convince me otherwise, feel free.

Anyway, I'm considering two possible options to handle the "injection" of configuration data into these component instances:

1. Plain vanilla Reflection - scan the type for configuration attributes and save the member info (along with the config key) in a static dictionary. Then use reflection methods such as `PropertyInfo.SetValue` and `PropertyInfo.GetValue` for the injection and extraction (for lack of a better term).  This is similar to the approach used by most DI libraries.
2. Use a dynamic proxy such as Castle and hook up an interceptor to the decorated properties, such that instead of referencing private/autogenerated fields, they reference the `IConfiguration` instance (i.e. the `get` method calls `IConfiguration.Get` and the `set` method calls `IConfiguration.Set`).  This is similar to the approach used by NHibernate and other ORMs.

The full implementation may end up being a fair amount of work, so I don't want to go *too* far down the wrong path before realizing I missed something.

So my question is, **what are the pros/cons of either approach, and what are the pitfalls I need to avoid?**  I'm thinking in broad terms of performance, maintainability, idiot-proofing, etc.

Or, alternatively, are there other, quicker paths to this goal, preferably which don't have steep learning curves?

Comment: Well, this is quite an old question of mine, and I don't have time to write a complete answer, but for anyone else who stumbles on this: I ended up using reflection for the initial scan and then compiling/caching delegates built using expression trees. I know it's not as fast as IL weaving but it's a major improvement on straight-up reflection and fast enough for the requirements here.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic proxy is much better approach. Define a "configuration" interceptor that injects the value from the configuration into your component (preferably lazily). Using Dynamic proxy, I'd also implement a generic IDisposable interface to your proxied Component, so that when the object is disposed or GC'd, it will persist configuration values based on the Peristence flag set in your attribute.